# Problems Enabling S3 Bucket Transfer Acceleration Using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am attempting to pull information about an S3 bucket using boto3. Here is the setup (*bucketname* is set to a valid S3 bucket name):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
result = s3.get_bucket_acl(Bucket=bucketname)
```

When I try, I get this error:

> ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the
>   GetBucketAcl operation: S3 Transfer Acceleration is not configured on
>   this bucket

So, I attempt to enable transfer acceleration:

```
s3.put_bucket_accelerate_configuration(Bucket=bucketname, AccelerateConfiguration={'Status': 'Enabled'})
```

But, I get this error, which seems silly, since the line above is attempting to configure the bucket. I do have IAM rights (Allow: *) to modify the bucket too:

> ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the
>   PutBucketAccelerateConfiguration operation: S3 Transfer Acceleration
>   is not configured on this bucket

Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Your response to the first error shouldn't be to enable transfer acceleration, but to understand why the request failed. Any chance that you have the following in your ~/.aws/config: s3 = use_accelerate_endpoint = true

Comment: The second request is failing because you are sending a request to enable the feature... using the endpoint that isn't available... because the feature is not enabled.

Comment: @jarmod, I did have that set in my config file and commented it out for testing. I'll post the answer to this problem shortly, since I've figured it out in full. Thank you for this pointer.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, "using the endpoint that isn't available" is exactly the root of this problem. See the Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I borrowed the code in the original question from the boto3 documentation, this construct is not complete and did not provide the connectivity that I expected:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

What is really needed are fully-initialized session and client handlers, like this (assuming that the profile variable is set correctly in the ~/.aws/config file and bucketname is a valid S3 bucket):

```
from boto3 import Session

session = Session(profile_name=profile)
client = session.client('s3')
result = client.get_bucket_acl(Bucket=bucketname)
```

After doing this (duh), I was able to connect with or without transfer acceleration.

Thanks to the commenters, since those comments led me to the solution.

Comment: Using s3 = boto3.client('s3') should be fine. The issue is, presumably, that your default credentials/config indicate that S3 requests should use the acceleration endpoints. That's probably not a good default configuration to have, because most buckets you interact with will presumably not be S3-accelerated. I would replicate that [default] config to [accel] and then change the default to remove use_accelerate_endpoint=true.